# Driver Manager applying changes.. stucks

Tags: drivers

i am trying to change the Display driver.
but it takes too long.
is it normal to take more then 20 miunts?

[image]

Comment: Close the Update Manager. Open a terminal and start `sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt-get install-f`. If there are error messages, add them into your question. If not, start `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346`.

Comment: This takes unusually long, since it will compile the graphics drivers from source. If you have a slow machine, it will take a while, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close the Update Manager. Open a terminal and start

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to repair the interrupted installation. Install the driver via

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Comment: Why is it asking me for a disc?? What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: if it's asking for a disk comment the line having cdrom in the /etc/apt/sources.list file and make an "apt update" - then repeat the steps above